# Reporting JESS's inference

Tags: jess

I'm trying to report the inference steps in JESS. For example, I would like to know which rules/facts caused inference engine to fire a certain rule. In order words, I want to see the theorem proving capabilities of JESS.
Here is an example from Wikipedia:

```
(defrule A ""
   (and (X croaks) (X eats flies))
   =>
   (assert (X is a frog))
)

(defrule B ""
   (and (X chirps) (X sings))
   =>
   (assert (X is a canary))
)

(defrule C ""
   (X is a frog)
   =>
   (assert (X is green))
)

(defrule D ""
   (X is a canary)
   =>
   (assert (X is yellow))
)
```

If I have the following:

```
(assert (X croaks))

(assert (X eats flies))
```

Then when I enter `(run)` then I will have `rule C` fired. It seems like, it's fired because of

```
(X is a frog)
```

but actually because of

```
(and (X croaks) (X eats flies))
```

I am not sure if I'm clear, but I wonder if there is any way that I can show why a certain rules is fired with a comlete inference process.

Comment: Do you have this in actual Jess code? How do you ascertain that a rule fires?

Comment: No, it's not in my actual code. For the example above, you can print out the facts via `(facts)` and see that new facts are added because of the execution of related rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to write some Java code, implementing jess.JessListener. You attach an object of this class to the Rete object, using `Rete.addJessListener(jess.JessListener)`. The event you are interesting in is `JessEvent.DEFRULE_FIRED`, and it'll contain a reference to the activation object, and the rule is available from that.

See the Javadoc for JessListener for some Java code.

You can attach the listener from CLP code, prior to `(run)`.

Comment: This was a very useful answer however it still gives me what exactly I'm looking for. Now, I'm able to see which immediate facts actually cause a rules activation. So, how can I know or can I  really know what the all inference process is? Basically, I need a backward chaining mechanism for proving a theorem. Do JESS allow it?

Comment: Well, if it gives you exactly what you are looking for then you have the answer for your question. If it does not you have asked the wrong question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant it still doesn't give me what exactly I'm looking for. So, my question in the comment above is still valid.

Comment: You need to write rules according to Jess' backward chaining. What you have shown is forward chaining.

Comment: I'll work on that and post any findings here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Lorderon -- you may also get what you want for forward chaining by simply keeping track of events over time. Using other events, you can determine which rule asserted a fact on its RHS, and you could therefore keep a database of which facts activated which rule which asserted which facts, etc. All the information you need is available using `JessListener`.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill -- Yes, I found `JessListener` very helpful. As you said, I've used it for tracking facts and rules. Thanks.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill -- I have another question. Is there any way that I can automatically report which immediate facts caused a rule being fired when I use JessListener? I can get the events whenever they happen, but it doesn't help me. Because one causing fact may be added before many other facts and I cannot easily tell that it was par of the pattern in the LHS of the rule.  Or, should I any use other interface for that?

Comment: @Lorderon yes, the object in the rule fired event is an activation record that contains the actual fact objects.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill this is great. I found how I could handle it. I've used this `((Activation) jess.getObject()).getToken().toString()` in my `JessListener`. Thanks a lot. BTW, I wish you had some examples in your book about the `JessListener`.